# Separable First Order Ordinary Differential Equation with Natural Logarithms

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Please check my work:

$$xy' = 5y$$

$$\int\frac{dy}{y} = 5\int\frac{dx}{x}$$

$$\ln y = 5\ln x + c$$

$$y = 5x + c$$

Is this correct?

Comment: $5\ln x+c$ is not $\ln(5x+c)$ but $\ln(\cdots)$?

Comment: I should have known better. You are right. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your solution, the fourth line is not a consequence of the third. A correct solution is

$$xy' = 5y$$

$$\int\frac{dy}{y} = 5\int\frac{dx}{x}$$

$$\ln y = 5\ln x + c$$

$$\ln y =\ln x^5+c$$

$$e^{\ln y} = e^{\ln x^5 + c}$$

$$e^{\ln y} = e^{\ln x^5}e^c$$

$$y = x^5e^c$$

$$y = Cx^5$$
where $C=e^c$.

Comment: I also have $y = x^5e^{c}$. Now I'm wondering if it's a good idea to leave the answer as that. Or do I have to do the $ C =e^c$ for my answer to be complete.

Comment: @usukidoll From mathematical point of view, there is no difference between them. It's just a matter of taste/aesthetic.

Comment: This was perfect. I just need to remember that x should never be zero else we divide by zero. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$e^{5ln(x)+c}=e^cx^5$ by properties of exponents. Since c was arbritary, you can write this as  $y=cx^5$ where c is another arbitrary constant.

Comment: Please fix. Your first equation isn't right.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

On your last step, recognize that $c = \ln c$, because $c$ and $\ln c$ are both arbitrary constants.

Invoking the rules of logarithms,

- $5 \ln x = \ln x^5$
- $\ln x^5 + \ln c = \ln cx^5$.

Putting all these together,
$$\ln y = 5 \ln x + c \implies \ln y = \ln x^5 + \ln c \implies \ln y = \ln (cx^5)$$
Now apply the antilog $e$ to both sides:
$$e^{\ln y}=e^{\ln(cx^5)}$$
and we are left with $$y=cx^5$$

Comment: Note that since $e^c$ is never $0$ or negative, in principle the calculation misses the solutions $y=0$, and $y=-17x^5$. To get the negatives, use the fact that $\int \frac{1}{t}\,dt=\ln(|t|)+C$. That still misses $y=0$. The separation is then incorrect.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution and domain and range.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the solutions are defined on the whole real line and are exactly the functions $y$ such that there exists some constants $(a,b)$ such that
$$
y(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}ax^5&\text{if}&x\gt0,\\ 0&\text{if}&x=0\\ bx^5&\text{if}&x\lt0.\end{array}\right.
$$
To prove this without dividing (by $y(x)$ when $y(x)=0$?) or taking the logarithm (of $y(x)\lt0$?), note that $xy'=5y$ implies that $y(0)=0$ and that the function $z$ defined by $z(x)=x^{-5}y(x)$ for every $x\ne0$ is such that $z'(x)=0$. Thus, $z$ is constant on $x\gt0$ and on $x\lt0$, QED.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/850179/).

Comment: Thank you for contributing a domain and range. These are often lost or ignored in the calculation of equations.

Comment: Thanks. Actually the main contribution of my post is not to "contribute a domain and range" (whatever that means...) but to avoid considering logarithms illegally. Any solution where the string of characters $\ln y$ or $\ln x$ or $\ln(x^5)$ appears, is incorrect.